# Touch Change Access, Modify AND Change

Tags: linux, timestamp, touch

I know you can use "touch" to change the access and modify timestamps of a file using the "-t" flag but is it possible to change the "change" timestamp. If so how would I go about doing this? Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 8):

You're asking how to set the `ctime` value of a file.  The only way to do that is to change the system date and then change the file, which is quite a crude method that will probably cause harm to the rest of your system.

If you're using `ext3` (maybe `ext2` and `ext4` also?) you can use `debugfs` to change it, but that requires that you unmount the filesystem first.  You can find info at [COMMAND LINE KUNG FU: Episode #80: Time Bandits](http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2010/02/episode-80-time-bandits.html)  (the start is about Windows; skip about halfway down to "Hal has the touch") to read about commands like this:  `debugfs -w -R 'set_inode_field /tmp/test ctime 200901010101' /dev/mapper/elk-root`

Without using filesystem metadata hackery like that, you can't do it.

Comment: Nice answer, deserves to be top.

Comment: Why is this functionality missing?