# How can I change 'change' date of file?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Touch Change Access, Modify AND Change](https://superuser.com/questions/397403/touch-change-access-modify-and-change)

How can I change 'change' date?

```
$ touch -t 9901010000 test;stat test
  File: `test'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fe01h/65025d    Inode: 11279017    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    x)   Gid: ( 1000/    x)
Access: 1999-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 1999-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
**Change: 2012-04-08 19:26:56.061614473 +0200**
 Birth: -
```

Comment: but there is no info how change st_ctime

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would like to set it to some arbitrary value.

Generally, you can not do that as it is not user settable the same way as access and creation times are.

You could change the system time to something you want, change the file, and change system time back, if you really want to. Or dismount the file system and edit it directly. That is not recommended though - you shouldn't have stuff depending on specific values for this information.